# Replacing values represented by 'UN' with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I came across the issue while practicing importing and summarizing data. Please any help?

Image seems not to show any error but I don't know how to figure the 'UN' and np.nan issue

```
# Names of the columns we're searching for missing values

columns = ['median', 'p25th', 'p75th']

# take a look at the dtypes
print(recent_grads[columns].dtypes)

# find how missing values are represented
print(recent_grads['median'].unique())
# replace missing values with NaN 
for column in columns:
    recent_grads.loc[recent_grads['median'] == 'UN', column] = np.nan
```

final output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use images to convey textual information. [Edit] your question to replace them with the respective code. Additionally, questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Without this, your question is off-topic and liable to be closed. Please construct a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it.

Comment: What problems/questions do you have?

Comment: We're not here to do your homework or answer your tests for you. Please do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

while reading csv, use the parameter 'na_values'.
    pd.read_csv('', na_values = 'UN')

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you need to import numpy and use nan to solve that problem the way they'd like it. 'nan', short for 'not a number' is what they want you to use to represent the absence of a value.

```
import numpy as np

# ... your code up to the last bit ...

for value in recent_grads['median'].unique():
    if value == 'UN':
        value = np.nan
```

Comment: This just changes the variable `value` within the loop, and does not modify the `DataFrame`

Comment: Exactly.. Use `.at` to index the particular location of the df